# Change button background color based on state - ColorStateList

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 5 buttons with icons, for 5 different colors ( blue, black, yellow, red, green) and i want them to change background color and icon tint if the user clicks on them (selects the option) then change back if the user clicks again (deselect the option).
[button state example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On6mE.png)

I know that you can do this with a ColorStateList xml, but i want to do this by code (the reason is that i dont want to create a lot of xml files - 5 for each button and 5 for the icons. If i got this wrong please help me).

The code that i have now is like this:

```
class MainMenuFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainMenuBinding

//Button States
val buttonStates = arrayOf(
    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected),
    intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_selected),
)

//Colors
val colors = arrayOf(R.color.blue, R.color.black, R.color.red, R.color.yellow, R.color.green)

//Initialisation of the ColorStateLists ... they are all the same because i need to initialise them
val redColorStateList = ColorStateList(buttonStates, intArrayOf(R.color.yellow, R.color.red))
val yellowColorStateList = ColorStateList(buttonStates, intArrayOf(R.color.yellow, R.color.red))
val blueColorStateList = ColorStateList(buttonStates, intArrayOf(R.color.yellow, R.color.red))
val blackColorStateList = ColorStateList(buttonStates, intArrayOf(R.color.yellow, R.color.red))
val greenColorStateList = ColorStateList(buttonStates, intArrayOf(R.color.yellow, R.color.red))

//Array of ColorStateLists
val stateLists = arrayOf(
    redColorStateList,
    yellowColorStateList,
    blueColorStateList,
    blackColorStateList,
    greenColorStateList
)


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    //Here i construct the ColorStateList for each color
    //R.color.material_on_primary_disabled is the same for all butons when they are not selected
    stateLists.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
        stateLists[index] = ColorStateList(
            buttonStates,
            intArrayOf(colors[index], R.color.material_on_primary_disabled)
        )
    }


    initButtons()

}


fun initButtons() {

    val butonPlayerBlue = binding.butonPlayerBlue
    val butonPlayerGreen = binding.butonPlayerGreen
    val butonPlayerBlack = binding.butonPlayerBlack
    val butonPlayerYellow = binding.butonPlayerYellow
    val butonPlayerRed = binding.butonPlayerRed
    val butonStart = binding.butonStart

    //ClickListeners
    listOf(
        butonPlayerBlue,
        butonPlayerGreen,
        butonPlayerBlack,
        butonPlayerYellow,
        butonPlayerRed
    ).forEach {
        it.setOnClickListener(::changeButtons)
    }


}


fun changeButtons(view: View) {
    // change state
    if (view.isSelected == false) {
        view.setSelected(true)
    } else {
        view.setSelected(false)
    }

    //setBackgroundTint just for one color ... to test it
    // --------------- HERE IS THE PROBLEM ------------------
    view.backgroundTintList = blackColorStateList
}
```

}

As it is, `view.backgroundTintList = blackColorStateList` changes the background color when i click the first time, but with another color (not the one set in the colorlist) and it does not change back on the following click.

[Now it looks like this when you click on the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk0Dw.png)

Right now i am working on the button background... i will get to the icon later.

Please help me understand what i am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using default state (empty int array) instead of "not selected" state?

Comment: Just did ... no changes.